# Using a value from an array to get a value from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have these 2 arrays. One array holds the names of colors. The other holds their hex values.

```
$availableColors = array("white","black");
$hexColors = array("white"=>"ffffff","black"=>"000000");
```

I'm hoping this would output `#ffffff`....

```
$hexColors[$availableColors'white'];
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `$hexColors[$availableColors[0]]` would make sense. `$availableColors'white'` doesn't.

Comment: In short: `echo '#'.$hexColors['white'];` will output `#ffffff`

Comment: is there a need to use 2 seperate arrays for this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your syntax is not correct.  Next, your `$availableColors` array is defined as:

```
[
    [0] => "white",
    [1] => "black"
]
```

Therefore if you want to get *white* out of it, you need to reference the 0's element:

```
$hexColors[$availableColors[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `$availableColors`, you can do directly

```
echo "#".$hexColors['white'];
```

Which will output `#ffffff`.

If you need the `$availableColors` for checking if the color is allowed/available.

```
$color = 'white';
if(in_array($color, $availableColors) {
    echo "#".$hexColors[$color];
} else {
    die('Color not allowed');
}
```

Comment: he could do `if(isset($hexColors[$color]))`.

Comment: That's correct, he could.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a non associative array by a text key; You should do this

```
echo $hexColors[$availableColors[0]];
```

Comment: @MShahzadKhan yep, it's a typo, thanks